# C++ программа, для вычисления суммы последовательности

Tags: c++, циклы

Вычислите сумму
S=1 * 3 + 3 * 5 + 5 * 7+... +(2n-1)(2n+1) для заданного n

Comment: StackOverflow - это не площадка для того, чтобы за вас решали задачи. В своём вопросе люди должны описывать конкретную проблему, с которой столкнулись, а не задачу, которую нужно решить.

Comment: И что вас останавливает? Про существование циклов вы уже знаете.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, раз MBo советует использовать цикл, и в метках тоже цикл...

Пуркуа бы и не па? Итак, через цикл.

```
int main()
{
    int n, a[3] = {4,6,-1};
    cin >> n;
    int m = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        m = (m + a[i])*n;
    cout << m/3 << endl;
}
```

Comment: Ну ведь вряд ли это задача на получение формулы суммы 4k^2-1

Comment: @MBo Стоп-стоп-стоп. Сумму считает? Считает. С циклами? С циклами. Условие выполнено? Выполнено. И, кроме того, выполнено условие ruSO — *не делать за любителей халявы домашние задания* :)

Answer (score 0):

Дана сумма:

[image: \sum_{k=1}^{n}{(2k+1)(2k-1)}]

Раскроем скобки:

[image: \sum_{k=1}^{n}{(4k^2-2k+2k-1)}]

`2k` и `-2k` сокращаются. Далее вынесем множитель 4 за знак суммы, а сумму единиц преобразуем в `n`:

[image: 4\sum_{k=1}^{n}{k^2}-n]

Далее, раскроем сумму квадратов чисел от 1 до n:

[image: 4\sum_{k=1}^{n}{k^2}-n=\frac{4}{6}(2n^3+3n^2+n)-n=\frac{4n^3+6n^2-n}{3}]

Вот вам и ответ. Циклы не нужны!

---

Можно и двумя циклами. Немного адаптируем пример Harry:

```
int main()
{
    int n, a[3] = {-1,6,4};
    cin >> n;
    int m = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        int p=1;
        for (int j=0; j<=i; ++j)
        {
            p *= n;
        }
        m += a[i]*p;
    }
    cout << m/3 << endl;
}
```

Comment: Простите, но возьмем, например, n = 2. Должно получиться 18. По вашей формуле имеем 8/3+4/2+5*2/6=16/6+12/6+10/6=38/6=19/3... P.S. Я, конечно, тоже так делал, но у меня вышло ((4n+6)n-1)n/3... Вы в одном месте со знаком ошиблись и про умножение забыли...

Comment: @Harry, ага, нашёл, сейчас поправлю